# ajax. access hidden value of html in div

Tags: ajax

I Wanna access the hidden values in ajex posted in a div

```
<input type="button" value="button 1" class="btn">
<div id="div"><div>

<script>
$.ajax({

url:"btn2.php", success:function(data){
$('#div').html(data);}
});

$( "#table" ).on( "click", ".upd", function() {
alert("button is wrking");
});

</script>
```

PHP

```
echo"<input type='button' value='button 2' class='btn'>
<input type='hidden' value='dishonest' id='hdn'>";
```

can any one help me on this.. i have no idea what to do ...

basically i want value of hidden

```
var h=$('#hid').val();
```

but that doesn't work bcoz its posted later in div ...

Comment: `var h = $('#hdn').val();` or `var h = $('#hdn').attr("value")`

Comment: This is not what i want .....
the #hid is not on html page .... but its in #div posted from php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get value from ajax success

```
success:function(data){
   $('#div').html(data);
   var h=$('#hid').val();
   alert(h);
}
```